# beanie.exceptions.CollectionWasNotInitialized error

Tags: python, mongodb, fastapi, odm

I'm new to the [`Beanie`](https://beanie-odm.dev/) library which is

> an asynchronous Python object-document mapper (ODM) for MongoDB. Data models are based on Pydantic.

I was trying this library with `fastAPI` framework, and made an ODM for some document, let's say it's name is `SomeClass` and then tried to insert some data in the db using this ODM.
Here's the code for ODM and the method to create a document (in`someClass.py`):

```py
from beanie import Document
from pydantic import Field, BaseModel
 
class SomeClassDto(BaseModel):
    """
    A Class for Data Transferring.
    """
    name: str = Field(max_length=maxsize, min_length=1)


class SomeClassDao:
    """
    This is a class which holds the 'SomeClass' class (inherited from Beanie Document),
    and also, the methods which use the 'SomeClass'  class.
    """
    class SomeClass(Document):
        name: str = Field(max_length=20, min_length=1)
        

    @classmethod
    async def create_some_class(cls, body: SomeClassDto):
        some_class = cls.SomeClass(**body.dict())
        return await cls.SomeClass.insert_one(some_class)
```

I've used and called the `create_some_class` function, but it throwed this error:
`beanie.exceptions.CollectionWasNotInitialized`

However the error is self-explanatory but I didn't understand at first, and couldn't find any relatable question about my problem in SO, so I decided to post this question and answer it, for the sake of future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error tells us, we should first Initialize the collection.
We should initialize the collection via the `init_beanie`.
I’ve used this function like this (in `databse.py`):

```py
from beanie import init_beanie
import motor.motor_asyncio
from someClass import SomeClassDao

async def init_db(cls):
            MONGO_DB_DATABASE_NAME = "SomeDBName"
            MOTOR_CLIENT = motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient()
            DATABASE = MOTOR_CLIENT[MONGO_DB_DATABASE_NAME]
            document_models = [SomeClassDao.SomeClass,]
            await init_beanie(database=cls.DATABASE, document_models=document_models)
```

And then we should use this function at the startup of the app, so we use it like this (in `main.py`):

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from database import init_db

app = FastAPI()
@app.on_event("startup")
async def start_db():
    await init_db()
```

- Then after creating the `init_beanie` function and adding the
  `document` we want to use to the `document_models`, it worked without
  error.

Hope this helps.